# How did the 2 spies which Yehoshua sent have authority to save Rachav and family

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, gentiles, joshua--book-of

[Devarim 20:16](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9984/jewish/Chapter-20.htm#v14) reads:

> טז. רַק מֵעָרֵי הָעַמִּים הָאֵלֶּה אֲשֶׁר יְהֹוָה אֱלֹהֶיךָ נֹתֵן לְךָ
>   נַחֲלָה **לֹא תְחַיֶּה כָּל נְשָׁמָה**׃
>
> However, of these peoples' cities, which the Lord, your God, gives you
>   as an inheritance, **you shall not allow any soul to live**.

Yet we see in [Yehoshua 2:14-19](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15786) that the spies promised to save Rachav and her family.

How did they have authority to promise this?

Answer (score 3):

See Megilla 14b that Rachav converted to Judaism. The Malbim to 2:11 therefore explains that she was exempt for the command to be killed.

Comment: all her family also converted?

Comment: @Danield Some meforshim definitely say so but I'll have time to look it up tomorrow.

Comment: Still, when the spies promised to save her and her family, they stipulated some conditions....and converting wasn't one of them (at least it's not clearly mentioned in the psukim there) - so then the question would remain: how could they sware?

Comment: @Danield (a) Malbim on 2:12 says "*והצלתם את נפשותינו ממות*, שהמוטל עליכם להציל אותנו לבל נהרג ע"י אחרים, וגם רמזה שיצילו נפשותיהם ממש ממות הרוחני, במה שיגיירו אותם". So: yes, converting her family was also hinted at. (b) Malbim on 2:12 says "אמרה הגם כי אחר שתעברו את הירדן לא תחיו כל נשמה, עתה השבעו טרם עברתם את הירדן, שהיה להם רשות לקבל גרים המשלימים עמם", that they could swear so because the verse you quoted only applied after _Benei Isra'el_ crossed the Jordan. Before that, they were obligated by Joshua's promise to accept those who wished to make peace with them.

Comment: So according to this, Rachav could have invited not only family members to her house  when Yehoshua would come to conquer Canaan, but also any canaanite who agreed to become Jewish... (How are we to fit this with the text?)

Comment: @Danield The spies made Rachav promise not to tell anyone about their conversation (2:14).

Comment: @Michoel what do you mean to say in your last comment?

Comment: @Danield You asked if Rachav could have invited any Canaanite who agreed to become Jewish. I answered that this was not the case because she promised to keep the conversation between them a secret.